# YII2 Editable Column does not work after PJAX

Tags: yii2, pjax

A column in gridview having EditableColumn integrated which works fine on each page load, but not after any PJAX call executions like search, pagination change etc.

In View EditableColumn code looks like this :

```
[
    'class' => EditableColumn::class,
    'attribute' => 'visit_status',
    'url' => ['update'],
    'type' => 'select',
    'editableOptions' => function ($model) {
        return [
            'source' => [
                'PENDING' => 'PENDING',
                'APPROVED' => 'APPROVED',
                'REJECTED' => 'REJECTED'
            ],
            'value' => $model->visit_status,
            'editable' => true
        ];
    },
],
```

And Controller Action is like below:

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $pk = unserialize(base64_decode(Yii::$app->request->post('pk')));
    $model = MyModel::findOne($pk);
    if ($model) {
        $model->visit_status = Yii::$app->request->post('value');
        if ($model->validate(['visit_status'])) {
            $model->save(false);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($model->getFirstError('visit_status'));
        }
    }
}
```

If PJAX is disabled then it works fine, but cant compromize PJAX for that

Comment: post also code from controller action

Comment: adding the EDitable column code here wont help rectify the issue please add complete view and your controller action code

Comment: Would be good to know if gridview is yii own gridview, kartik GridView or somthing else. Also would be good to see entire widget setup not only one column. I assume it is kartik's GridView and that case do you have widget option "pjax: true", as default is "false".

Comment: Added controller action in question.